# Is initialized non final static variables are thread safe?

Tags: java, concurrency

Assume, I have a private non final static variable, and initialized in the static block, and it is not modified after initialization and has no methods to modify the variable. Is it threadsafe?

```
class Test
{
     private static int value = 10;

     public static int getValue()
     {
        return value;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'non final'.  final makes variables constant.  But is there some reason you do not want a global constant value? Being static only affects the scope of the variable, not whether it can be written or not.  I'm confused.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at -- Are you asking about the possibility of modification of private member variables? Another thread (or the same thread, for that matter) could potentially change the value of a private member variable using reflection:   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: I just wanted to know what guarantee JVM provides with non final static variables with no methods to modify the variable in terms of thread safety, where multiple threads try to read the data.

Comment: You're getting *constant variables* mixed up with *immutable objects*. A variable that is marked final is constant, meaning it cannot be changed. But constant  variables are not always thread safe (in the case of reference variables), since threads can still modify the value through methods. An immutable object is an object who's state cannot be modified, which makes it thread safe since threads will only be accessing the value, and it will never change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just wanted to know what guarantee JVM provides with non final static variables with no methods to modify the variable in terms of thread safety, where multiple threads try to read the data.

The procedure for initializing a class ([JLS 11.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)) states that that initialization is performed while holding a lock.  I think that this implies that any thread that refers to the statics after initialization has completed will see the fully initialized state.

You might get into trouble if you had a situation where the static initialization of one class created and started a thread that could observe the static variables of another class before they latter's static initialization completed.  In that case, it may not be possible to guarantee that the thread will see the initialized state.

---

The other think to note is that we are only talking about the values in the static variables here.  If those variables refer to mutable objects or arrays, and those objects / arrays are mutated, then your code is not automatically thread-safe.

This illustrates a larger point.  You can't actually talk about the thread-safety of variables in isolation.  The accepted definition of thread-safety is that the introduction of threading does not result in incorrect behaviour of something.  Variables don't have behaviour.  Behaviour is an application level thing, though it is sometimes meaningful to consider the behaviour of a part of an application; e.g. some classes or methods in a particular application context.

---

Reading between the lines ... you seem to be trying to avoid the "overheads" of synchronization in your usage of statics.  That is all well and good ... but the thread-safety, static initialization and the memory model are all some of the most difficult / hard to understand parts of the Java language.  Many really smart people have (in the past) tried and failed when implementing "clever" or "efficient" ways of reducing synchronization overheads.

My advice: don't try to be too smart.  Keep it simple.  The synchronization overheads are not large enough (IMO) to risk introducing "heisenbugs" into your code-base.

And finally, it is generally accepted that static variables, and especially mutable static variables are bad OO design.  I would advise you to consider revising your design to eliminate them.

Comment: I am not quite sure about your statement "You might get into trouble if you had a situation where the static initialization of one class created and started a thread that could observe the static variables of another class before they latter's static initialization completed. In that case, it may not be possible to guarantee that the thread will see the initialized state." Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: public static Holder holder = new Holder(42); this statement is threadsafe and mentioned in JCIP book.

Comment: JLS 12.4.1 says *"The fact that initialization code is unrestricted allows examples to be constructed where the value of a class variable can be observed when it still has its initial default value, before its initializing expression is evaluated, but such examples are rare in practice. (Such examples can be also constructed for instance variable initialization (§12.5).) The full power of the Java programming language is available in these initializers; programmers must exercise some care."*

Comment: Yes - the JCIP example is thread-safe ... for the reasons I stated in my Answer.